# como crear un ejecutable con pyinstaller para un programa que incluya todas las carpetas para su funcionamiento

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Tengo un proyecto hecho en Python 3 con tkinter  al convertirlo ejecutable no me incluye todas las carpetas que necesita mi proyecto para funcionar, me crea el ejecutable pero no me agrega las carpetas para que funcione tengo que mover los archivos y carpetas al directorio dist que genera Pyinstaller para que funcione correctamente.

```
pyinstaller --onefile inicio.py
```

Pyinstaller puede incluirme todas las carpetas y archivos que necesito para no estar cambiandolos al directorio dist para que corra sin ningún problema.

Comment: Has intentado agregar el directorio del archivo principal de esta forma `--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>`, *;* se usa en Windows y *:* para Linux, ese parámetro es para agregar archivos no binarios al ejecutable donde `<SRC...` es la ruta, puedes intentar escribir carpeta por carpeta desde `"C:\"` o desde la carpeta principal del proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando utilizas *pyinstaller* sin el argumento `--onefile` simplemente tienes que utilizar el argumento `--add-data` para añadir los *recursos de la aplicación* al directorio de salida (*dist*).

Por ejemplo, si quieres añadir una carpeta llamada *resources* harías lo siguiente:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "resources;." inicio.py
```

De esta manera se copia la carpeta resources en *dist*.

Si quieres crear un *standalone* mediante `--onefile` ejecutarías lo siguiente:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "resources;." inicio.py
```

Con lo que se habrá generado un ejecutable *inicio.exe* en el directorio *dist*. La carpeta *resources* está comprimida dentro de *inicio.exe*.

**Siendo *inicio.exe* un *standalone*, al ejecutarlo se descomprimen todos los recursos de la aplicación en un directorio temporal**. Este directorio temporal es diferente cada vez que ejecutes el programa, y es borrado automáticamente siempre que tu aplicación finalice con éxito.

Tu programa no funcionará correctamente porque **el directorio de trabajo** (el que devuelve `os.getcwd()`) **es diferente del directorio temporal donde se han extraído los recursos de la aplicación**. Los recursos de tu aplicación no están en `os.getcwd()`.

*Pyinstaller* define una variable en el *módulo sys*. Esta variable es `sys._MEIPASS`, y su valor es el *path* del directorio temporal utilizado durante la *ejecución actual*.

En *inicio.py* **debes comprobar si existe `sys._MEIPASS`**. En caso afirmativo tienes que cambiar el directorio de trabajo para que `os.getcwd() == sys._MEIPASS`.

```
import sys, os

if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'): # True para inicio.exe, False para inicio.py
    os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)   # Ahora se cumple: os.getcwd() == sys._MEIPASS
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

```
pyinstaller -n "nombreExe" --add-data "recursos;recursos" -F -w -i recursos/logo.ico app.py
```

-> `-n` Darle un nombre al ejecutable o tomará por default el del archivo principal `.py`, en este caso `app.py`

> `--add-data`: puedes cargar aquí tus recursos, si los hay
> `-i`: Ponerle un icono al ejecutable
> `app.py`: debe ser tu archivo principal que contiene `if __name__ == 'main':`
> `-F`: Indicarle a pyinstaller que deseas crear un ejecutable de un solo archivo.
> `-w`: No abrir ventana de consola `cmd`

Si usas imágenes e iconos debes crear añadir lo siguiente para que logre encontrarlas: `tempDir = sys._MEIPASS`, y concatenarlo a todas tus rutas con estructura `iconApp = os.path.join(tempDir,"dirRecursos\\icon.ico")` y después asignarla.

NOTA: El IDE puede enviar advertencia en `sys._MEIPASS`, puedes ignorarlo, solo es para `pyinstaller` cuando ya esté tu ejecutable